# POST https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute net::ERR_ABORTED 415

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am continuously getting this error:

> **POST https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute net::ERR_ABORTED 415**.

The API that I have used: **https://docs.jdoodle.com/compiler-api/compiler-api**. Code to fetch data:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(APIData);
    await fetch("https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute", {
      mode: "no-cors",
      method: "POST",
      body: {
        clientId: "e463db2adee1eed75d5839b6a3e9430f",
        clientSecret:
          "3ce3725c3a88ecd385ce9efd2048b0c11658072b9e98f9d7b8943ef3f3f247c7",
        script: 'console.log("hello world")',
        stdin: "",
        language: "nodejs",
        versionIndex: "0",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data.data()))
      .catch((e) => console.log(e.message));
```

I am doing it in ReactJS using `fetch()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status code 415 (unsupported media type) means your request was rejected due to an invalid content-type. On its [API FAQ](https://docs.jdoodle.com/compiler-api/compiler-api#what-is-the-request-endpoint-for-compiler-api), JDoodle is clear that it only accepts json types.

So, you need to add

```js
headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

to your axios request to send data to that API.

Comment: `mode: "no-cors"` also needs to be removed because it blocks the setting of content-types which aren't valid for HTML's `<form enctype>` attribute.

Comment: Thank you @samuei got the right response!

Comment: Glad I could help!